# HTML AgilityPack Note Finding Header

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to pull data from a website.

and am having trouble  pulling out some Header details.  My code just skips over the headers It's the "`<h4 class`" that I am trying to pull out.

Also different browsers contain different data.

for example.

```
    <section class="results-list">
      <header>
        <h3>U.S. House</h3>
      </header>

      <section class="results-group">
        <header>
          <h4 class="district">Florida 1st congressional district</h4>
        </header>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row clearfix">



<article class="results fifty">

  <header>
    <h4>Democrat primary</h4>
  </header>

  <section class="results-table">
    <table>
      <tr class="header results-table-row">
        <th class="vote-percent">Percent</th>
        <th class="candidate">Candidate</th>
        <th class="vote-count">Votes</th>
        <th class="winning">Winner</th>
      </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="vote-percent">55%</td>
          <td class="candidate">Jennifer Zimmerman</td>
          <td class="vote-count">13090</td>
          <td class="winning">WINNER</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
  </section>
</article>
```

Here is my code.

```
        foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
        {
            var temp = table.InnerHtml.ToString();

            foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
            {
                ResultsListBox.Items.Add(row.InnerText.ToString());

                foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td"))
                {
                    ResultsListBox.Items.Add(cell.InnerText.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("cell: " + cell.InnerText);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: var url = @"https://www.politico.com/election-results/2018/florida/";
            var data = new MyWebClient().DownloadString(url);  // server data
            var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(data);

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there is only one header that you want to get in the page that is `h4` element with `class` attribute, you can try the following XPath query :

```
var queryHeader = "//section/header/h4[@class]";
var header = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(queryHeader);
Console.WriteLine("header: " + header.InnerText);
```

Comment: Har, What if there are multiple headers?